# filling holes for 3d image

Tags: matlab, 3d

I want to use morphology operator for filling holes of a 3d image. The 3d image consists of 116 2-D image slices of the same size (512*512 pixels). I tried using imfill in Matlab for the 3d image but the result is not what I wanted. The small holes are filled and other holes are not filled

When I tried using imfill slice by slice the result is correct. Is there any way for filling holes in 3d images? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a for loop that uses `imfill` slice by slice? you stated that this works already.

Alternatively, here's an option from the file exchange: [Region Growing](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32532-region-growing-2d3d-grayscale) - a recursive region growing algorithm for 2D/3D grayscale images with polygon and binary mask output.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote https://github.com/seung-lab/fill_voids which will fill topological holes rapidly.

Alternatively, there is SciPy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html